# Creating an R data.frame column based on the difference between two character columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a data.frame, df, where I have 2 columns, one with the title of a song and the other with the combined title and artist. I wish to create a separate artist field.
The first three rows are shown here

```
title                               titleArtist
I'll Never Smile Again  I'll Never Smile Again TOMMY DORSEY & HIS ORCHESTRA / FRANK SINATRA & PIED PIPERS
Imagination         Imagination GLENN MILLER & HIS ORCHESTRA / RAY EBERLE
The Breeze And I    The Breeze And I JIMMY DORSEY & HIS ORCHESTRA / BOB EBERLY
```

There are no issues on this set of data with this code

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

 df %>% 
 head(3) %>% 
 mutate(artist=str_to_title(str_trim(str_replace(titleArtist,title,"")))) %>% 
 select(artist,title)

 artist                                                         title
1 Tommy Dorsey & His Orchestra / Frank Sinatra & Pied Pipers I'll Never Smile Again
2                  Jimmy Dorsey & His Orchestra / Bob Eberly       The Breeze And I
 3                  Glenn Miller & His Orchestra / Ray Eberle            Imagination
```

But when I apply it to thousands of rows i get the error

```
Error: Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)

#or for part of the mutation

df$artist <-str_replace(df$titleArtist,df$title,"")

Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, replacement, opts_regex =    attr(pattern,  : 
 Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN)
```

I have removed all parentheses from the columns and the code appears to work for a while before I get the error

```
Error: Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

Is it another special character that might be causing an issue or might it be something else?

TIA

Comment: Does `traceback()` give you any information about what triggered the error?

Comment: Does using `gsub` or `sub` throw the same error as str_replace? I see you have `/` in titleArtist - could it also occur in title?  Hard to really analyze this issue without access to the data.

Comment: Check to see if you have empty title and/or artist. May have to use `ifese()`.

Comment: Tx for suggestions. traceback() did not provide, me at least, with any meaningful information e.g row number of first error. There are '/'s in title as well  (occurring when the record had two A sides). I succeeded in replacing with '&' but am still getting same error - though whether it is related to '&' or something else I cannot tell. Is there a list of proscribed characters in addition to '(' and '/' any of which could  contributing to issue

Comment: @dww. I have uploaded to googlesheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xHbRE77HrHYIlj4dChuOZz45ZPjuMKngqQUnobL0cwY/edit#gid=1828378253

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your general problem is that `str_replace` is treating your `artist` values as regular expressions, so there are a lot of potential errors due to special characters beyond parentheses.  The `stringi` library, which `stringr` wraps and simplifies, allows more fine-grained controls, including treating arguments as fixed strings instead of regexes.  I don't have your original data but this works when I throw some error-causing characters in:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)


df = data_frame(title = c("I'll Never Smile Again (",  "Imagination.*", "The Breeze And I(?>="),
           titleArtist = c("I'll Never Smile Again ( TOMMY DORSEY & HIS ORCHESTRA / FRANK SINATRA & PIED PIPERS",
                            "Imagination.* GLENN MILLER & HIS ORCHESTRA / RAY EBERLE",
                            "The Breeze And I(?>= JIMMY DORSEY & HIS ORCHESTRA / BOB EBERLY"))

df %>%
  mutate(artist=stri_trans_totitle(stri_trim(stri_replace_first_fixed(titleArtist,title,"")))) %>% 
  select(artist,title)
```

Results:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

artist                     title
(chr)                     (chr)
1 Tommy Dorsey & His Orchestra / Frank Sinatra & Pied Pipers I'll Never Smile Again (
2                  Glenn Miller & His Orchestra / Ray Eberle             Imagination.*
3                  Jimmy Dorsey & His Orchestra / Bob Eberly      The Breeze And I(?>=
```

Comment: I note that `stringr::str_replace(titleArtist, fixed(title), "")` is equivalent to `stringi::stri_replace_first_fixed(titleArtist, title, "")`.

Comment: Looks like it works a charm Thanks for both solution and explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
 df <- data.frame(ID=11:13, T_A=c('a/b','b/c','x/y'))  # T_A Title/Artist 
   ID T_A
 1 11 a/b
 2 12 b/c
 3 13 x/y

 # Title Artist are separated by /
 > within(df, T_A<-data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(T_A), '/', fixed=TRUE))))
  ID T_A.X1 T_A.X2
 1 11      a      b
 2 12      b      c
 3 13      x      y
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not trying to split the column based on '/'. For row 1, I would be trying to separate the titleArtist column into  "I'll Never Smile Again" and  "TOMMY DORSEY & HIS ORCHESTRA / FRANK SINATRA"